# Partial Padding and Border concealed with overflow: hidden;

Tags: html, css

If we have the following **HTML**

```
<div id="i">
        <a href="#">StackOverflow</a>
</div>
```

With the following **CSS**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#i
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#i a
{
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
    border: black 1px solid;
}
```

When I modify the **CSS** to toggle *overflow: hidden* on/off, (as shown in the picture below) we can see that the top and bottom padding and border is being hidden when overflow is set to hidden, Yet the left and right padding and border is allowed to flow. Why is this and how can I allow the full padding and border to flow.( I do not want to lose any of it but require *overflow: hidden* as its a fix to the common [*float: * problem](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) )

[image]

There are actually 2 problems here, it seems that also when we remove *overflow: hidden* we still lose the top padding at the browser ceiling, I also do not know why this occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is happening because the `<a>` element is an `inline` element. If you make the `<a>` an `inline-block` (i.e. `display: inline-block`), then the top padding should show.

I'm not too clear on what you mean by "how can I allow the full padding and border to flow", though.